# I get taken back to the xeondm login screen after trying to login on OpenBSD

Tags: login, openbsd, bsd

I am trying to start MWM by default. I edited the `$HOME/.xsession` script to make OpenBSD boot with MWM by default instead of FVWM, After I rebooted OpenBSD. I tried to login with xenodm, and all it did is take me back to the xenodm login display. I tried booting-in into single-user mode and did some tweaks to try to get vi and xterm to work, but am still unable to edit vi files on single-user mode. I tried disabling xenodm on single-user mode as well, but never worked. How can I solve this issue properly?

Answer (score 1):

Start with `$HOME/.xsession-errors`, it should show you the errors. BTW your `$HOME/.xsession` should be executable and if not then it is executed by `/bin/sh`, see https://github.com/openbsd/xenocara/blob/master/app/xenodm/config/Xsession.in